# Выделять ли оборот "прежде всего" запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> В этих тезисах констатировался(,) прежде всего(,) тот факт, что в «количественном отношении целый ряд организаций является массовыми организациями".

Answer (score 1):

Ваш случай - обособлять или нет - на полное Ваше усмотрение.

---

Отвечает Грамота.ру:

**[Вопрос № 234104](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20234104)**

> Здравствуйте, ответьте мне, пожалуйста, является ли (в большинстве
>   случаев) "прежде всего" вводным оборотом и надо ли выделять его
>   запятыми в середине предложения. Я уже задавала этот вопрос два дня
>   назад, ответа не получила. Для наглядности приведу пример:    "Выбор
>   технологий обучения зависит прежде всего от возраста учащихся". Нужны
>   ли здесь запятые до и после "прежде всего"?
>
> С уважением, Ольга.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Слова *прежде всего* могут выступать в роли вводных и как члены
>   предложения, однако разграничить эти случаи зачастую затруднительно, и
>   решение об обособлении принимает автор текста. В приведенном примере
>   запятые лучше не ставить.
>
> ---

**[ПРЕЖДЕ ВСЕГО, *вводное сочетание*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_627&v=full)**

> То же, что «во-первых, главное». Подробно о пунктуации при вводных
>   словах и сочетаниях см. в [Прил. 2.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2)
>
> ***Прежде всего***, – что это за прическа? И. Бунин, Легкое дыхание. *Да и
>   вообще ты это оставь; **прежде всего,** это невежливо.* В. Гаршин, Встреча.
>   *«**Прежде всего** ­– дикая рябина или садовая?» – «Была дикая, сейчас
>   растет на участке»*. А. Яшин, Угощаю рябиной. *Однако это было совсем не
>   так. **Прежде всего**, оба директора имели паспорта, дипломы, пропуска и
>   другие необходимые документы. Самые же сложные дубли не могли иметь
>   никаких удостоверений личности.* А. и Б. Стругацкие, Понедельник
>   начинается в субботу.
>
> **! Не смешивать** с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «сперва, вначале, в первую очередь»).
>
> *«Я всей душой желал быть тем, чем вы хотели бы, чтоб я был; но я ни в
>   ком никогда не находил помощи... Впрочем, я сам **прежде всего** виноват
>   во всём. Помогите мне, научите меня и, может быть, я буду...» – Пьер
>   не мог говорить дальше; он засопел носом и отвернулся.* Л. Толстой,
>   Война и мир. *Поговоривши с родителями невесты и получив согласие,
>   Лапкин **прежде всего** побежал в сад и принялся искать Колю.* А. Чехов,
>   Злой мальчик. *Ухаживая за девицей, обращай внимание **прежде всего** на
>   наружность, ибо по наружности узнается характер особы.* А. Чехов,
>   Руководство для желающих жениться. ***Прежде всего*** я прочел сказку о
>   стойком оловянном солдатике и маленькой прелестной плясунье, потом –
>   сказку о снежной королеве. К. Паустовский, Сказочник. *Предатель в
>   разведке **прежде всего** открывает имена друзей…* Ю. Семенов, Отчаяние.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь *трудно* усмотреть вводный оборот. Место расположения и смысл сочетания таковы, что оно воспринимается как обстоятельство образа действия, выраженного глаголом, и заменяется напр. наречием "преимущественно" или "сначала". Вводным (т. е. *обособляемым*) оборотом это сочетание было бы в начале предложения, но смысл при этом несколько изменился бы: предложение выглядело бы аргументацией (если не возражением) некоему собеседнику, в то время как в исходном варианте оно имеет описательный характер и ссылается выражением "прежде всего" на приоритеты автора цитируемого источника (возможно даже, тот просто *начал* с упомянутого "факта").

Answer (score 1):

**В этих тезисах констатировался прежде всего тот факт, что...**

По-моему, здесь не вводное, а член предложения, который запятыми не выделяется.